# How to copy the whole sheet and paste results in a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the whole contents from one sheet (source) to another specific sheet (destination), in the same spreadsheet (Google Sheets)

How can I achieve that?

I tried `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet()`, but this creates a new sheet every time I trigger the script

Comment: For example, how about using `copyTo(destination)`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that you already have a trigger set up and you want to make it copy all the contents of one sheet into another. Well, in that case you only need to use [`Range.copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) as @Tanaike suggested. Take this as one of the possible solutions:

```js
function so64978677() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  sourceSheet.getDataRange().copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));
}
```

Please, don't hesitate to ask me any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your example and answer, works perfectly well!